# How to "append" Op at the beginning of a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a `GraphDef` proto file which I am importing using `tf.import_graph_def`. Ops can be added at the end of the graph like this:

```
final_tensor = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='', return_elements=['final_tensor'])
new_tensor = some_op(final_tensor)
```

But I want to add Ops at the beginning of the graph, so essentially the first Op in the graph_def needs to take the output of my Op as input, how do I do it?

Comment: you can use contrib.graph_editor to replace an existing input tensor in graphddef with new input tensor, ie `reroute_a2b_ts` -- https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/contrib.graph_editor/module_reroute

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks. But I want to forward prop on the graph inside a function which will be used to map (tf.map_fn) on some input. I can't think of a way to use graph_editor without editing the graph_def during each function execution and importing it into python graph. Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: it should have same time/code complexity as doing `some_op(final_tensor)`. IE, you wrap the logic and call `replace_input(previous_input_tensor)` each time you need to prepend something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found a way to do this. I am sure the function Yarolsav mentioned in the comments does something similar internally.

```
new_input = graph_def.node.add()
new_input.op = 'new_op_name'  # eg: 'Const', 'Placeholder', 'Add' etc
new_input.name = 'some_new_name'
# set any attributes you want for new_input here
old_input.input[0] = 'some_new_name'  #  must match with the name above
```

For details about how to set the attributes, see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/python/transform_graph_test.py) file.

Comment: when trying to access `old_input.input[0]` I receive `AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'input'`

Comment: @user3085931 You can try to use `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node` instead of `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()`.

Answer (score 0):

The script @Priyatham gives in the link is a good example how to add node in tf graph_def. `name`, `op`, `input`, `attr` are 4 required elements. `name` and `op` could be assigned, whereas `input` should use `extend` and `attr` should use `CopyFrom` method for assignment, like:

```py
new_node = graph_def.node.add()
new_node.op = "Cast"
new_node.name = "To_Float"
new_node.input.extend(["To_Float"])
new_node.attr["DstT"].CopyFrom(attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=types_pb2.DT_FLOAT))
new_node.attr["SrcT"].CopyFrom(attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=types_pb2.DT_FLOAT))
new_node.attr["Truncate"].CopyFrom(attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(b=True))
```